# debugging a graphical msdos game

Tags: debugging, dos, dos-exe, graphics

There is a DOS game I want to run through a debugger. I tried using (FreeDos) 
DEBUG.COM over DosBox. But the problem is that this game uses graphics, and this messes up the output of DEBUG.COM.

Is there some way (it can be by choosing other debugger) to separate the graphical output of the game and the textual output of the debugger?

Answer (score 4):

Please check this guide https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=3944
DosBox has additional internal debugger, but it has to be build with support for that.